# I want to add 2 months to a date ensuring the date falls to following Monday.

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Example my current date is 09-March-2017 if i add 2 months it will be 09-May-2017 (Tuesday) but wherein i need this to fall to 15-May-2017 which is following Monday.

Kindly help me with the formula. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If in Cell C4 is your input date, put the following formula in Cell E4

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(C4),MONTH(C4)+2,DAY(C4)))=2,DATE(YEAR(C4),MONTH(C4)+2,DAY(C4)),(DATE(YEAR(C4),MONTH(C4)+2,DAY(C4)))+7-WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(C4),MONTH(C4)+2,DAY(C4)))+7-2))
```

[image]

Note that this formula does not give you following Monday in case date + 2 months fall on Monday, (Highlighted green above) but if you want it that way just need to add 7 Days for such condition using IF.

Comment: Nice approach !

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly... this was a great help :)